# Beginner PHP learner trying to use Salt encryption

Tags: php, salt

I'm trying to put together a PHP login script and have noticed that storing my database paswords in plain text form is not secure. Is my connect.php file secure? How would I use a salt encryption into my connect.php file below?

Thanks and sorry for a basic question, I am still very new to PHP.

```
<?php

if(!defined('INCLUDE_CHECK')) die('You are not allowed to execute this file directly');


/* Database config */

$db_host        = 'localhost';
$db_user        = 'randomuser';
$db_pass        = '123456';
$db_database    = 'randomdatabase'; 

/* End config */



$link = mysql_connect($db_host,$db_user,$db_pass) or die('Unable to establish a DB    connection');

mysql_select_db($db_database,$link);
mysql_query("SET names UTF8");

?>
```

Comment: You don't have and won't hash your source code :)

Comment: If by "salt encryption" you mean "use a salt while hashing the password" that refers to any user-password, not the db connection one

Answer (score 2):

> Is my connect.php file secure?

To some extent - yes.

> How would I use a salt encryption into my connect.php file below?

You can't use whatever "salt encryption" with your connect.php. Just leave it as is.

Answer (score 0):

First I recommend studying a few articles about encryption, hashing and salting, to get a general feel on what it does and what it doesn't do.

Wikipedia doesn't know it all, but the articles are there cover the most relevant parts.

- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Encryption
- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptographic_hash_function
- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Salt_(cryptography)

Passwords for php scripts are usually not encrypted. Best practise is to store it in a separate configuration file (p.e. config.php). This way its up to your system administrators to secure this. This doesn't only help your security, such an external configuration file makes it easier to port an application. Most major php applications, from forum engines, CMS, calendars or whatever, use this kind of architecture.

Answer (score 0):

It's secure.
It depends on your hosting provider and it's setting.
For secure projects I recommend using at least VDS.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe an additional answer. Yes, as far as I know, there's no other way to store database connection credentials than storing it in plaintext.

Maybe you can encrypt your credentials using an encryption scheme, but if the attacker have access to your files (and your encryption scheme), they can decrypt your encrypted credentials easily.

Your `connect.php` is secure as long as you keep it secured. Some suggestions:

- Put your `connect.php` outside webserver's root directory (you still can include it from any other script) to prevent access from HTTP
- Keep it `php`, don't rename the file to any other extension that will served by the webserver as a viewable text file
- If you want, you can protect your `connect.php` with some `.htaccess` rules

Answer (score 0):

> Is my connect.php file secure?

You may want to encrypt your connect.php with ioncube... http://www.ioncube.com/ ...for what it can still protect.

I like to add stuff like this in my .htaccess :

```
<files connect.php>
order allow,deny
deny from all
</files>
```